# Using eth-lightwallet and truffle

Tags: truffle, eth-lightwallet

I've tested with accounts created and unlocked in geth and my sample app works fine. I'm now going distributed with my accounts and have added eth-lightwallet and HookedWeb3Provider to put the account management on the user end.

I generate a couple of addresses and then try to create a contract. However I get the message 'account is locked'.

I've configured the hookedwebprovider as in the samples:

```
var web3Provider = new HookedWeb3Provider({
      host: "http://myaddress:8545",
      transaction_signer: keystore
    });
web3.setProvider(web3Provider);
```

Then try to use the generated addresses

```
 var account = keystore.getAddresses()[0];
 MyContract.new({from: account, gas: 10000000});
```

I had expected the error to be something like insufficent ether/gas, since the balances are 0. Do I need to call the new function in a different way or configure something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the provider for each contract. So you'll do:

```
MyContract.setProvider(web3Provider);
```